# Is there a way to catch the "objects are not valid as a react child" with static checking?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I just had a bug that would cause my application to crash, because I had `{object.field}` in the JSX, but `{object.field}` was an object type, therefore not a valid React child

I am using esLint and Typescript, so the static checker is aware of the fact that I'm trying to output an object type in the JSX

Is there a way to be warned about this error directly in the IDE?

I tried looking at IDE extensions, but could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when you try to pass an object directly to a React component as a prop or child.
You need to convert it into a valid React child by rendering it as a React element

It is likely your field is also some kind of object, also including arrays, that React cannot render by itself
You must iterate over its values and render them as React elements
For example, lets assume `object.field` looks like

```js
const staff = [
    name: 'Billy', role: 'admin'},
    name: 'Sally', role: 'contributor'}
];
```

To render it I'll use `.map()` method to iterate over each object in the list and render it as an HTML element

```js
{staff.map(user => (
    <div key={user.name}>
        <p>{user.name}</p>
        <p>{user.role}</p>
    </div>
))}
```

React doesn't know how to render a JavaScript object, which is why it throws the error.

In case you're sending an React Element in `object.field`, you can checkits validity by calling `React.isValidElement`.

Details of how it works can be found in the [beta documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/isValidElement) (Its be documentation, not the function that's in beta stage).

It will check that whatever value `object.field` holds is in fact an React Element

Comment: Read the question again. They are asking how you would catch this error with static analysis (namely TypeScript). They aren't asking how to render something correctly or fix this error.